# Programmatically creating a MOSS publishing page

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I'm getting an error when creating a MOSS publishing page (this is a completely clean MOSS install, no site built into it yet). I'm using code which I've found on plenty of blogs, eg:

```
var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(Site.RootWeb);
SPContentTypeId ctId = new SPContentTypeId(contentTypeId);
var layouts = pubWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts(ctId);
var layout = layouts[0];

var url = pageTitle.EndsWith(".aspx") ? pageTitle : pageTitle + ".aspx";
var newPage = pubWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add(url, layout);
```

But when I do the `pubWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add` method call I get the following error:

> FormatException - Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

I've checked the following:

- ContentTypeId is valid
- layout has a value
- pubWeb.GetPublishingPages().Count == 1

I can't seem to find anything useful via Google nor can I find anything in Reflector which could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, the ContentType I was using was corrupt. Because of another problem I'm having deploying ContentTypes ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539328/high-cpu-usage-when-deploying-content-types-via-a-sharepoint-feature)) I'm programatically creating the ContentType, but deploying the PageLayout with CAML. This resulted in the AssociatedContentType being incorrect, so when I created the page using it MOSS was unable to determine what ContentType to use and fell over.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the web that you are using is a Publishing Web. To quote MSDN's article on [GetPublishingWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497306.aspx):-

> Before you use this method, check the
>   IsPublishingWeb method to confirm that
>   publishing behavior is supported on
>   this instance of the SPWeb class. If
>   publishing is not supported on the
>   SPWeb, then the methods and properties
>   of the PublishingWeb wrapper may
>   behave unexpectedly.

```
// Get the PublishingWeb wrapper for the SPWeb that was passed in.
PublishingWeb publishingWeb = null;
if (PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(web))
{
    publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
}
else
{
    throw new System.ArgumentException("The SPWeb must be a PublishingWeb", "web");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a site to the farm and then, use [this code from social msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/f1f9eddf-ab85-4b73-bc26-857eda23d12f/):

```
public void FillPublishingWebWithPages 
    (string publishingSiteCollection, int pagesToCreate)
        {
        try
        {
           using ( SPSite site = new SPSite( publishingSiteCollection ) )
          {
             using ( SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb() )
             {
                  PublishingSite pubSite = new PublishingSite( site );
                  PublishingWeb pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb( web );
                  SPContentTypeId articleContentTypeID = 
                  new SPContentTypeId( "0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F"+ 
                      "2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B242478" );

        PageLayout[] layouts = pubWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts( articleContentTypeID );
        PageLayout articlePageLayout = layouts[ 1 ];
        // create a temp name...
        string pageName = DateTime.Now.ToString( "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss" );
        // create the specified number of pages
        for ( int i = 0; i < pagesToCreate; i++ )
        {
              PublishingPage newPage = 
pubWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add( string.Format( "{0}_Gend_Page_{1}.aspx", pageName, i ), articlePageLayout );

          newPage.Title = "Hello";
          newPage.ListItem[ "PublishingContactName" ] = "valuetest";    
          newPage.Update();
          newPage.ListItem.File.CheckIn( "created" );
          newPage.ListItem.File.Publish( "created" );
          newPage.ListItem.File.Approve( "created" );
          pubWeb.Update();
        }

        web.Update();

        }

        }

        }

        catch ( Exception ex )

        {

          throw new Exception( 
          "Error in Page CREATION ----FillPublishingWebWithPages----", ex );

        }

        return;

        }
```

Example Call:

```
FillPublishingWebWithPages( http://server:12345/sites/test/subsite1/subsite2/Pages/, 5 );
```